# openstack fails to create an instance after integrating with rbd ceph

Tags: openstack, ceph, openstack-nova

I have configured openstack kolla to enable ceph for glance, cinder and nova. I must say that cinder and glance are working perfectly fine with ceph. Nova on the other hand refuses to work properly. When i launch an instance, the instance is getting stuck in spawning state and nova-compute goes down. I did go through the config file of nova and everything seems to be on point along with the ceph keyrings and etc.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to see which exact rbd comman(s) fail(s) if you enable debug logs for nova-compute. Can you verify that the nova keyring works as expected? Try something like `rbd --id cinder -k /etc/ceph/ceph.client.cinder.keyring -p nova ls`. Adjust paths and file names to your needs. The default ceph user for nova is "cinder" in the globals.yaml. Is `nova_backend_ceph` also set to `yes`?

Comment: This works for me (look up nova-compute container and execute command in the container):
`(kolla) [tbenutzer@rocky-kolla ~]$ sudo docker ps | grep nova-compute` ---
`(nova-compute)[nova@rocky-kolla /]$ rbd --id cinder -k /etc/ceph/ceph.client.cinder.keyring -p nova ls`

Comment: nova_backend_ceph is enabled with yes parameter. The keyring is also working, I am able to list the pool from the container. However the log doesn't seem to be giving any hints at what is might be wrong. When launching an instance in openstack, I have the nova-compute.log tailed. I noticed that the log stops at "Creating image(s)". Nothing about ceph whatsoever. When nova is not attached to ceph it works perfectly fine.

Comment: seems like the rbd commands like creating image are working in cinder-volume container but not in nova-compute container even though both containers are using the same keyring.

Comment: Can you create a test rbd image from within nova-compute like so: `rbd --id cinder -k /etc/ceph/ceph.client.cinder.keyring create nova/testimage -s 10`, and then run the `ls` command again to see if the image was created. If the manual command works but nova can't do it automatically, I'd enable debug logs.

Comment: And also please add the cinder client caps:`ceph auth get client.cinder`, just for completeness sake (add them to the question).